# Help with Proof by Induction using Primes

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $p$ a prime, and $a_1,a_2,...a_n$ integers such that $p$ divides the product $a_1a_2...a_n$. Prove by induction that $p|a_i$ for some $i$, $1\leq i \leq n$.

I am unsure how to go about this proof. It has been a while since I have done an induction proof. I know that you have to show it works for a few values and then prove that it works for $n+1$.

Comment: Well, can you prove it for $n=2$?

Answer (score 1):

We have that $p\mid a_1$ implies $p\mid a_1$.

We also have that $p\mid a_1a_2$ implies $p\mid a_1$ or $p\mid a_2$ by unique prime factorisation of $a_1a_2$, $a_1$, and $a_2$. This is your base case.

Assume that $p\mid \prod_{i=1}^n a_i$ implies $p\mid a_j$ for $1\le n\le m$.

Consider when $n=m+1$: we have $p\mid (a_1\dots a_m)a_{m+1}$. If $p\mid a_{m+1}$, we are done; otherwise, $p\mid (a_1\dots a_m)$ by the base case, which then implies $p\mid a_j$ for some $j\in\overline{1, m}$ by the induction hypothesis, and we are done.

Comment: i understand how you did the base case...however after that i get a little confused. where does everything after that come into play? i am looking for some further clarification/explanation.

Comment: You split $a_1a_2\dots a_{n+1}$ in a product of two integers then use the base case, @rover2. Does that make sense?

Comment: What's the first sentence you get stuck at, @rover2?

Comment: i get stuck at what you are assuming. basically where you start the induction. "...implies $p|a_j$ for $1\leq n \leq m$..." @Shaun

Comment: I'm assuming that if $p\mid a_1a_2\dots a_n$ then $p\mid a_j$ for some $j\in\{1, \dots , n\}$ for all $n\in\{1, 2, \dots , m\}$; that is, I'm using strong induction. Strong induction isn't actually necessary though: it's a relic of my first attempt. The induction hypothesis should be that if $p\mid a_1a_2\dots a_n$ then $p\mid a_j$ for some $j\in\overline{1, n}$.

Comment: okay i am starting to understand what you did...when you said $p|a_j$ for $1\leq n \leq m$ where did the $n$ and $m$ come into play since you put $a_j$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65832/discussion-between-shaun-and-rover2).